# Running OSGI in Eclipse, generic way?

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, eclipse-pde, pde

I'm trying to launch a OSGI framework stack in debug mode in eclipse, and i wonder if there's a common way of doing it.

First of all, i know i must configure Eclipse **Plugin Development -> Target Platform** for it to find my bundles and be able to develop easily with **PDE**. Let say i want to try my application on a **Geronimo** stack, i'll have to create a new **Target Platform** by hand, and manually add every bundle geronimo uses, and they are each in a separate folder... Same thing for **Karaf**, **ServiceMix**, **Knopflerfish** or any other stack i wanna try out. Is there another way of creating that **Target Platform**?

Then, in the **OSGi Framework** launch configuration, whatever how is your **Target Platform** configured, by default the framework is **Equinox** and the only way i've found to change this is to install some eclipse plugins.

I've found that **Karaf** provides EIK plugin which adds the **Karaf** framework. It hasn't been update for a long time, and i'm not even sure it supports **Kepler**...

There's also **Pax-Runner-Eclipse-Ui**, which is no longer updated too. If you use the last available version of this plugin, you'll find that it provides a limited set of configurations, which includes several versions of **Equinox**, **Felix** and **Concierge**. AFAIK, these settings are directly packaged in the plugin, and there's no way to add a custom one (like a Karaf configuration, for example). And anyway, that plugin is helpful for running your bundles in differents frameworks, but the bundles used at runtime won't automatically appear in your **Target Platform** so you can develop against that particular framework.

How do peoples usually work??
I'm trying to get things working for months, but i can't find a way to easily try some stacks in development mode.

Some single bundles are easy to make working (service discovery, blueprint injection...), but having a complete stack with JSF, JPA and Transaction support is not a trivial thing to do, even after reading **OSGi in Action**, and **Enterprise OSGi in Action**.

Did i miss something?

Comment: Why are you using PDE?

Comment: In fact, i don't have a real project to work on, i'm just exploring the possibilities being offered by OSGi.I'm using PDE to debug my bundles so i can follow service injection, class versions and so on. Since you're asking, i guess you have something else to propose than PDE? I'm not tied to it.

Comment: Naturally I would suggest [Bndtools](http://bndtools.org/) which will make your life much, much easier. In relation to your question for example, you would be able to configure multiple Repositories, in a much more flexible way than permitted by PDE's Target Platform concept.

Comment: Great! I'll try that tonight. Maybe you could make this comment an answer so you'ld get points.

Comment: Just in case you want to debug Karaf, do use remote debugging for this.

Comment: It effectively works like a charm. Really nice tool you made! Having the right tools makes developing so much fun!